# Google App Engine may be discarding http header

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm testing an application on Google App Engine.

I use the Flexible environment with a custom python runtime.

In my application I need a "session.id" header on HTTP requests.

My web application code extracts the value of session.id and validates it, if it's invalid or missing the web application returns HTTP 401.

When I issue a HTTP POST to my GAE web application using `curl` and setting the header, e.g.:

`curl -v -X POST --data "echo" -H "session.id: someweirdandlargestring"  https://*****.appspot.com/echo`

it seems GAE proxy removes the "session.id" header, then the web app returns 401. If I send "session.id" as a Cookie everything works fine and the server returns 200. I've debugged the application and the header does not reach the web application.

I've read the docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled) and they describe headers that are expected to be removed or added from requests before they reach our actual server. But they say:

> For security purposes, some headers are sanitized or amended by intermediate proxies before they reach the application.

What makes believe me GAE is removing the HTTP header I've set.

My questions:

Is this an expected behavior from GAE?

What would you suggest to fix it? In order words: how to make my header entry to reach the web server application code?

*Note that using a cookie is not an option in short term.*

Comment: Have you tried to post with a header key not composed of "."(dot)? Cause it's not common to use dot in a header, and maybe that's causing the unexpected behavior somewhere.

Comment: And, do you get a response back from server? with what status code?

Comment: @viz, I will try removing the dot. About the response code I've edited, it returns 401 because my code expectes the header to be there to perform auth but it's not there.

Comment: If you have full control over the name of the header, I would suggest trying a random name for the header like 'YodaToken'. If you can do that, I don't think the google-app-engine would do any sanitization on your custom header. Please try and let me know.

Comment: And I don't think it would be the case but check on your header value if it's really large, cause some client or server have some policy on header limit, so make sure it's not that large.

Comment: Also it's good idea to sniff your network or use other client as postman to figure out if the problem is on client side or on the server side.

Comment: @viz, you are right about the dot, if I use, let's say, "sessionid" the header reaches the server. GAE web servers are discarding malformed http headers. Thanks!! I will post as an answer for the records.

Answer (score 2):

As @viz has suggested I've tested a header name without the dot. It works.

If I use, let's say, "sessionid", then the header reaches the server.

GAE web servers are discarding malformed http headers.
The best I've found about HTTP header conventions are on NGINX docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers:

> Valid names are composed of English letters, digits, hyphens, and possibly underscores

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, please let me bring this September 21 update, as I bumped intot he same issue for PHP7, which GAE was seemingly discarding my "api_secret" header for (not really RFC-ish, it is?). I deployed a little debugging tool which dumped the headers, and carried on experiments.

Outcome:

1. headers are forced to camel case;
2. `apisecret` became `Apisecret`;
3. `api-secret` became `Api-Secret`;
4. `api.secret` was discarded;

I finally chose `X-Api-Secret`, to be in line with [RFC2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) recommendation for user-defined headers.